# How do I fix the "Failed to recompile android resource files." build issue?

Tags: unity, android, build-process

I've tried similar solutions I found on this website, nothing worked. There are thee errors that pop up... been banging my head for quite a while now, please help!

Also note: I updated my JDK using the download link (next to the browse option in the external preferences). Then linked it to this file, which I am lead to believe is the correct file. C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-9

1. ```
   Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:
   -bootclasspath "C:/NVPACK/android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -d "C:\Users\Dylan\Desktop\ContentCreater\Repo\DoodlePlanes\DoodlePlanes\DoodlePlanes\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "com\android\vending\billing\R.java" "com\SoloDeveloperStudio\DoodlePlane\R.java" "com\unity\purchasing\R.java" "com\unity\purchasing\googleplay\R.java"
   warning: [options] source value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
   warning: [options] target value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
   warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
   3 warnings

   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
   ```
2. ```
   UnityException: Resource compilation failed!
   Failed to recompile android resource files. See the Console for details.
   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex)
   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message)
   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuildPointToConsole (System.String title, System.String message)
   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.CompileResources (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report)
   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
   UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:263)
   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
   ```
3. ```
   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Build failed with errors.
     at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x001b9] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:162 
     at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00050] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:83 
   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
   ```

Comment: Please see this Thread : https://forum.unity.com/threads/java-9-jdk-9-support-by-unity-android.499354/

Answer (score 1):

use jdk 8 because 9 is not compatible 
or
 change your package name it might help you.
in my case when i changed the package name then it works fine.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained how to switch the JDK or package name, or what to change the package name into (eg. are there special characters that should be avoided in package names? How should a developer distinguish between a good package name to use and one that could cause problems?)

Answer (score -1):

it worked thx all.

for me jdk path was the point.i changed the path to 1.8.25 folder.

and change the target API and minimum lv to 26,19 in androidManifast 파일.

only two files in the asset>plugin>android.

Comment: Can you please explain this answer in more detail? Imagine another developer is having the same problem, and walk them through what they need to fix step by step, using complete sentences.